# postgresql-simple: get a list of table names in a database

Tags: database, haskell

I am connected with postgresql-simple and need to get a list of tables in the current db.

- psql has \d
- haskelldb has 'tables', which yields the dbTables attribute in the connection object (i think that's what it was called)
- HDBC has getTables

what is the way to do this in postgresql-simple?

thanks,
m.

Comment: (I have found table pg_type, which contains some table names i am expecting when i grep it.  I will look into that some further...)

Comment: ah.  rubber-duck software consulting.  :-)  the answer is that you don't use it with postgresql-simple at all.  you use SQL:

    select schemaname, tablename from pg_tables;

quite obvious table name, too.  thanks everybody for listening!

Comment: I suggest you add this as an answer. Then (after 48 hours, I think), you can accept your own answer. This will help others know that the question has been answered. You get points, for this. You even get a badge for the first time you answer your own question. ;^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as already answered in a comment above (due to lack of privileges): don't use postgresql-simple at all, but plain SQL on the internal postgresql tables:

```
select schemaname, tablename from pg_tables;
```

sorry for the noise.